# Error in Custom Widget of FlutterFlow: "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:video_video_player.dart'"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am following a tutorial to use Custom Widgest in FlutterFlow, re-using dependencies from pub.dev. However many people in the YouTube comments (including myself) hit an error whilst trying to compile the custom widget. The widget is an official Flutter.Dev widget for a video player.

I have tried searching for this error, however most responses involve installing more packages and restarting Android Studio etc, however this error is happening within FlutterFlow itself, which I haven't seen an answer for.

[image: FlutterFlow code with error]

Original tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM2gwA2VHyc&ab_channel=JamesNoCode

Pub.dev link:
https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/example

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Did you add the package video_player to your pubspec.yaml? Did you run "flutter pub get"?

Comment: Hi @JoRa - can I edit pubspec.yaml in FlutterFlow directly? I haven't touched that file before so not sure how to do it. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

First pf all you have to add dependenc of video player imleft side you are suggested to add video player dependency forst of all add it and you can esaily use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore the error because FlutterFlow can't detect the dependency in real-time.

Just hit `Compile & Preview` button and it magically works.

[image]